# Show bytes transfered on an active connection

Tags: linux, network-monitoring, realtime

Is it possible to show bytes transfered over time in real-time on an active connection on the command line? I can do netstat and get the bytes at that time, but wonder if it can be adapted to show total number of bytes transfered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you mean by connection. If it is ppp connection, then use `ifconfig`. If you are referring to TCP connection, the you can use `iptraf`. If you want for a specific connection and to analyze the traffic use `wireshark`.